# Getting a ERROR 1064 (42000) ) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, shell, mysql-error-1064

Hi im not very good a this as i have nust started learning shell scripts. i keep getting this error and i have no clue what is causing it.

Here is my code below.

```
mysql -u root -p'password'  <<-EOFMYSQL
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS KF4005AL; 
USE KF4005AL;
CREATE TABLE filedata (filename VARCHAR(20), userid VARCHAR(20), groupid VARCHAR(20), permissions VARCHAR(20), filesize NUM, lastaccessdate DATE, lastaccesstime TIME, lastmodification TIME, creationdate DATE, creationtime TIME);
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filedata.txt' INTO TABLE filedata;
SELECT *  FROM filedata ORDER BY last access date INTO OUTFILE 'var/lib/mysql-files/sqlout.txt'; 
QUIT;
EOFMYSQL
```

fi

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation on [datatypes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-types.html). `NUM` is not a valid one. Maybe you wanted `NUMERIC`.

And remove the spaces in `last access date` to get `lastaccessdate` what you actually named that column. Otherwise you'll have the next issue there.

Comment: cheers thanks very much. i did that and it came up with many more errors, but ive sorted it now thanks!